# DirectShow cannot detect PS3eye

Tags: camera, directshow

I'm trying to use a PS3eye camera on Windows 10 with DirectShow sdk.
I've installed the driver and tested in AMCap that the PS3eye is working.

When in VS 2015, I defined a CCameraDS class with a function called CameraCount(), but when I call this function it always returns me 1 which represents the EasyCamera of my laptop. Am I missing something?

```
int CCameraDS::CameraCount()
{
    int count = 0;
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // enumerate all video capture devices
    ICreateDevEnum *pCreateDevEnum = 0;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void**)&pCreateDevEnum);

    IEnumMoniker *pEm = 0;
    hr = pCreateDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEm, 0);
    if (hr != NOERROR) 
    {
        return count;
    }

    pEm->Reset();
    ULONG cFetched;
    IMoniker *pM;
    while(hr = pEm->Next(1, &pM, &cFetched), hr==S_OK)
    {
        count++;
    }

    pCreateDevEnum = NULL;
    pEm = NULL;
    return count;
}
```

To verify, I have another method called CameraName(),

```
int CCameraDS::CameraName(int nCamID, char* sName, int nBufferSize)
{
    int count = 0;
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // enumerate all video capture devices
    ICreateDevEnum *pCreateDevEnum = 0;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void**)&pCreateDevEnum);

    IEnumMoniker *pEm = 0;
    hr = pCreateDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEm, 0);
    if (hr != NOERROR) return 0;
    pEm->Reset();
    ULONG cFetched;
    IMoniker *pM;
    while(hr = pEm->Next(1, &pM, &cFetched), hr==S_OK)
    {
        if (count == nCamID)
        {
            IPropertyBag *pBag=0;
            hr = pM->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void **)&pBag);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                VARIANT var;
                var.vt = VT_BSTR;
                hr = pBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, NULL); 
                if(hr == NOERROR)
                {
                    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,var.bstrVal,-1,sName, nBufferSize ,"",NULL);

                    SysFreeString(var.bstrVal);             
                }
                pBag->Release();
            }
            pM->Release();
            break;
            }
        count++;
    }
    pCreateDevEnum = NULL;
    pEm = NULL;
    return 1;
}
```

When I input 0, I have EasyCamera returned, but input 1 with nothing output. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

In fact, the PS3eye driver as well as AMCap software are both compiled under x86 environment, since I used x64 environment, the driver wasn't working I think.

I didn't expect this to be the solution but it does solve the problem.